# Republishing mDNS to another network

Tags: networking, dns, mdns

Is it possible to configure a DNS server to "republish" (actually: forward requests to) a multicast DNS system on a network it's on?

To give a concrete example, I have a site-to-site VPN set up between networks A and B, both of which have their own subnet, but can route to each other. Naturally, the multicast mDNS queries and responses don't traverse the VPN tunnel (and I wouldn't want them to, because there would be name collisions). Is it possible to set a DNS server (ideally something lightweight like dnsmasq) up on network A so that when it receives a request for `somehost.network-a.domain` (perhaps from a device on network B) it makes a multicast request for `somehost.local` and returns the result it recieves, if any, to the requestor as the IP of `somehost.network-a.domain`?

Comment: "mdns proxy" search turned this as first hit: https://github.com/wisq/mdns-proxy , https://github.com/fenik/mdns-proxy as second hit. It appears they work in opposite direction (and wisq's is the feature you're asking about)

Comment: @A.B after a little configuration, the first one is indeed exactly what I'm looking for. I've no idea why the term "proxy" didn't occur to me. If you add this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8766.html describes what you are looking for.